# Connection reset by peer using sshfs

Tags: ssh, sshfs

I am using a fuse/sshfs mount which worked fine so far. Now I had to reinstall the server system and suddenly getting the classic `read: Connection reset by peer` error. I am using public key authentication and copied my key to the newly installed system. Normal ssh login works fine. I changed the log to debug but sadly this doesn't give me any useful information:

```
sshd[2077]: debug1: Forked child 2198.
sshd[2198]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
sshd[2198]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
sshd[2198]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
sshd[2198]: Connection from 192.168.1.6 port 47991
sshd[2198]: debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4
sshd[2198]: debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4 pat OpenSSH*
sshd[2198]: debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
sshd[2198]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4
sshd[2198]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 103/65534 [preauth]
sshd[2198]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
sshd[2198]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
sshd[2198]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
sshd[2198]: debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none [preauth]
sshd[2198]: debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none [preauth]
sshd[2198]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
sshd[2198]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
sshd[2198]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
sshd[2198]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.6 [preauth]
sshd[2198]: debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
sshd[2198]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
sshd[2198]: debug1: do_cleanup
sshd[2198]: debug1: Killing privsep child 2199
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am missing here?

**UPDATE**

The `auth.log` with debug level 3:

```
sshd[2455]: debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
sshd[2455]: debug1: Forked child 2456.
sshd[2455]: debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 751
sshd[2455]: debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
sshd[2455]: debug3: send_rexec_state: done
sshd[2456]: debug3: oom_adjust_restore
sshd[2456]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
sshd[2456]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
sshd[2456]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
sshd[2456]: Connection from 192.168.1.6 port 50037
sshd[2456]: debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4
sshd[2456]: debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4 pat OpenSSH*
sshd[2456]: debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
sshd[2456]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4
sshd[2456]: debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
sshd[2456]: debug2: Network child is on pid 2457
sshd[2456]: debug3: preauth child monitor started
sshd[2456]: debug3: privsep user:group 103:65534 [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 103/65534 [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0  [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0  [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5 [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5 [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug3: mm_key_sign entering [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 5 [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug3: mm_key_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 6 [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
sshd[2456]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 5
sshd[2456]: debug3: mm_answer_sign
sshd[2456]: debug3: mm_answer_sign: signature 0x7f9b687c7680(100)
sshd[2456]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6
sshd[2456]: debug2: monitor_read: 5 used once, disabling now
sshd[2456]: debug2: kex_derive_keys [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
sshd[2456]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.6 [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering [preauth]
sshd[2456]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
sshd[2456]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
sshd[2456]: debug1: do_cleanup
sshd[2456]: debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering
sshd[2456]: debug1: Killing privsep child 2457
```

**UPDATE**

I tried a manual `sshfs` mount and I also get `read: Connection reset by peer`. I then added the debuging options and also got `Permission denied (publickey).`. This is strange since the public key is in place and works fine otherwise. I also use my user for the ssh connection and manually specify the private key file. Could this be an issue with the root account not beeing able to access the correct public key on the server somewhere? I'm executing

```
sudo sshfs myuser@myserver:/mnt/foo /mnt/foo -o IdentityFile=/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and the relevant log part is

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
read: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: The output looks exactly like one from a ssh session which refuses to connect due to server key fingerprint mismatch (or an unknown key). Does `sftp` to the server work correctly?

Comment: I tried sftp with both Nautilus (`Connect to Server...` option) and Filezilla. It works fine. Although Filezilla asked my about an unknown host key.

Comment: Try `sftp` directly - that is what SSHFS uses.

Comment: @peterph works perfectly

Comment: Strange... the client and server logs don't seem to match: server log ends before key exchange is finished, client makes it to authentication.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After a lot more of trying it turns out my client user wasn't in the `fuse` group. After I added it with `sudo usermod -a -G fuse myuser` the mount works fine again. Don't ask me how it could have worked before reinstalling the server. Thank for all your help!

Comment: is this the user on the local or remote file system?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow to be honest I don't know anymore :D My best guess would be local, since this is where you use fuse.

Comment: or `gpasswd --add USER fuse`

Comment: In my case, I simply needed the port number.  This was added with the `-p` option.

Answer (score 52):

Since this error message is the default one when ssh connection fails, the most generic answer (per @peterph comment) is to investigate using at least `-odebug`:

```
sshfs -odebug,sshfs_debug,loglevel=debug ...
```

for example

```
sshfs -odebug,sshfs_debug,loglevel=debug -o Ciphers=arcfour -o Compression=no -o allow_root -o transform_symlinks localhost:/ /mnt/your_mount_point
```

As said elsewhere, common causes include missing `allow_other` in `fuse.conf` or missing `fuse` group  membership (although that may not be needed anymore on Ubuntu 18.04?)

In my case this printed:

`SSHFS version 2.8
FUSE library version: 2.9.7
nullpath_ok: 0
nopath: 0
utime_omit_ok: 0
executing <ssh> <-x> <-a> <-oClearAllForwardings=yes> <-ologlevel=debug> <-oIdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa> <-oCiphers=arcfour> <-oCompression=no> <-2> <localhost> <-s> <sftp>
command-line line 0: Bad SSH2 cipher spec 'arcfour'.
read: Connection reset by peer`

...pointing to an unsupported Cipher option (working on fedora but not ubuntu)

Comment: Using `-o debug`, I got **command-line line 0: Bad SSH2 cipher spec 'arcfour'.**

Comment: Or in my case something much simpler: `Could not resolve hostname` because I typed it in wrong and didn't notice. Lol. Good tip for debugging

Comment: Excellent, also for me using `sudo` before `sshfs`  make run command with superuser that have not any resolve in `.ssh/config`. `Could not resolve hostname` solved by run command with current user.

Answer (score 33):

I was using the `-F /path/to/config` option. The answer was in my config file where I had

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

which did not work. The absolute path is required:

```
IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: `man ssh-config` explicitely allows tilde for `IdentityFile`

Comment: @CharlesB I have tested it both ways and I assure you my answer is valid. And I do see what you're referencing in the man pages. Perhaps it's a bug when running with sudo? (because I am)

Comment: sure, if you're running sshfs with sudo, tilde is the home of the root user. then you need to specify absolute path.

Comment: Even if you use absolute paths in your `~/.ssh/config` file, running `sudo sshfs` will by default read root's `/root/.ssh/config` file (if any). You need to pass the explicit path to your config file via `-F`.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue today.
`ssh` connection is OK, `sshfs` is not.
My SSH server is Qnap NAS (TS-228).

The problem was fixed by **enabling SFTP** on NAS device.

Additional setting appeared in `sshd_config`:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/sftp-server
```

Comment: Enabling SFTP on my Synology NAS also resolved the error for me. BUT the content displayed in the mounted folder is not the same as when connecting directly via ssh. Folders are missing and the root cannot be accessed. Bummer.

Comment: I had to change mine to `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` and then ran `systemctl restart sshd` to get this to work.

Answer (score 8):

Just in case someone stumbles over this thread: I had this `read: Connection reset by peer` error because the host name **was not resolvable** (I was not using a fully-qualified host). Using the right host name solved the issue - the error message is just completely misleading then.

A good test is to ssh to the machine before running the sshfs command, if that does not even work sshfs will not work either.

Comment: sshfs server-ssh-alias:/some/dir /mnt didn't work for me, but sshfs real.servername.org:/some/dir /mnt did work for me. (combined with user_allow_other)

Comment: indeed, I could not belive it but I have to use the local IP otherwise it s not wirking

Comment: same here: ssh works but sshfs did not - because I used it with sudo and then the entry in `~/.ssh/config` was not found. in my case, I did the mount in userland and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

I found my problem, which was similar, had to do with the fuse configuration file in:

```
/etc/fuse.conf
```

I had to un-comment:

```
user_allow_other
```

Answer (score 4):

Got the same error while running `sudo sshfs [...] myhost: /mnt/myhost`, where `myhost` is defined in my `~/.ssh/config` files.

The problem is that running `sudo sshfs` didn't look in my home directory for `~/.ssh/config`, but in `root`s. The solution was to pass explicitly the config file via `-F`:

```
sudo sshfs -F /home/dandv/.ssh/config [...] myhost: /mnt/myhost
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this error and tried the methods above and failed at making it work.

The problem was the server was not accepting ssh at port 22. I used:

```
$sshfs -p 2222 user@server:/path/to/folder ~/local/path
```

and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

My error was serverside. The sftp subsystem for sshd is apparently defaulted to not available on newer centos 7.6.xx . fixed by removing "#" from in front of the following in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

`Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server`

thanks to eddygeek for the -odebug recipe to help finding this issue.
Same as GEOM above but not specific to Qnap.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and when I checked the network config, system some how lost the gateway address. So I ran the below command

route add default gw 192.169.0.254 
 and then rebooted the system.

Issue is resolved after the reboot.

Comment: You got "connection reset by peer" with a bad gateway?!?

Answer (score 1):

I erased the host's fingerprint from /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts (actually deleted the whole file) and it fixed it... because the fingerprint had changed.  using ssh to connect to the host gave a clear reason of why it was not connecting.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for a **very** simple solution:
After running sshfs in debug mode, I found that my connection was broken.

Turn on verbose mode with switch:

```
-o debug
```

Comment: `-o debug,sshfs_debug,loglevel=debug` wll give you more info

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the server interface not being up after a long time on startup. The server is connected to a Cisco switch port with trunk mode. Since any trunk port will do various checks before actually become UP (usually more than 30 seconds), this has resulted in the above connection reset error message.

My solution was to change the switch port to access mode with `spanning-tree portfast`, since in my environment the trunk mode is unnecessary for this server.

I also found out about this issue using the debugging parameter to sshfs.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone was still having issues and is an idiot like me, make sure you didn't create the new directory (on your local system) using `sudo`.

Because then you, (the local user), won't have write access to it.

Which makes it impossible to use as a mount point.

Quick fix for this is `sudo chown -R localuser:localuser ~/directory_you_created`

(Swap out localuser with your actual username).

Cheers.

Comment: somewhat related (stupid root tricks):  if using something like clonezilla, make sure you are running sshfs as the user you think you are running it as.  Just because you fixed the host keys as $normaluser doesn't mean you fixed them as $root  (clonezilla runs as root)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. These options helped me:

`sshfs -odebug,sshfs_debug,loglevel=debug`

In return I got:

*SSHFS version 2.10.0
fuse: bad mount point `allow_other,default_permissions,IdentityFile=/home/rbr/.ssh/id_rsa': No such file or directory*

...which gave me the direction where to look for.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I tried to contact the same server with normal `ssh`, it gave me this: [image]

Which for me was accurate; it *had* changed.

It informed me that I could resolve that with this command:

```
ssh-keygen -f "/path/to/known_hosts" -R REMOTE_IP
```

After doing that, and running `sshfs` again, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, and I comment on the solution in case it works for someone else.

I was trying to mount a NAS on a raspberry. On the NAS I use SSH on port 2222, while SFTP goes on port 22.

I was able to find the error using the command from a previous comment:

```
sshfs -p 2222 -odebug,sshfs_debug,loglevel=debug -o Compression=no -o allow_root -o transform_symlinks user@ip:/ /mnt/folder

................
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
subsystem request failed on channel 0
read: Connection reset by peer
```

My mistake was that I was trying to mount via SSH port 2222, when I simply had to leave default 22 for SFTP.

```
sshfs user@ip:/ /mnt/folder
```

So simple and so functional.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem which was caused by DNS.
Ping and ssh directly worked, but

```
sshfs -o debug <hostname>:/ /mnt/<directory>
SSHFS version 3.7.0
executing <ssh> <-x> <-a> <-oClearAllForwardings=yes> <-2> <hardie.isode.net> <-s> <sftp>
ssh: Could not resolve hostname hardie.isode.net: Name or service not known
read: Connection reset by peer
```

The DNS result was being returned by my router, but SSHFs was clearly not working and -o debug showed why.
Adding the host to /etc/hosts enabled it to work.
It's not clear why it was needed (which is obviously not ideal).
(Fedora 32)

Answer (score 0):

I was also receiving the `read: Connection reset by peer` error.  The file permissions on my ssh key were incorrect. Once adjusted as described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/215506/1794379), the sshfs mount started working. My issue was specifically the private key file permissions were `644` instead of the required `600` due to copying my `~/.ssh` folder over from a backup after a fresh install. The linked answer is pasted below:

- .ssh directory: 700 (drwx------)
- public key (.pub file): 644 (-rw-r--r--)
- private key (id_rsa): 600 (-rw-------)
- lastly your home directory should not be writeable by the group or others (at most 755 (drwxr-xr-x)).

Answer (score 0):

I use `sudo ssh username@ip` and then exit from remote server, and then `sudo sshfs ...`, this issue gone! I'm accessing Ubuntu 20.04.6 from Ubuntu 20.04.6