# How to make sshfs work?

Tags: ubuntu, sshfs, fuse

I want to mount the remote fs that I connect through ssh so that I can use an editor to edit the files. I installed `sshfs` for this.

Running the command:

```
sudo sshfs ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ /mnt/ec2-deep/
```

gives me this error:

> read: Connection reset by peer

I tried to remove this error by adding my user to fuse(which was the suggestion [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94720/connection-reset-by-peer-using-sshfs))
But it tells me that there's no group called fuse in my system.
What should I do to make `sshfs` work?

My environment is:

OS : Ubuntu 16.04

Output of `aptitude show fuse` :

```
Package: fuse                     
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 2.9.4-1ubuntu3.1
Priority: standard
Section: utils
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Uncompressed Size: 106 k
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libfuse2 (= 2.9.4-1ubuntu3.1), adduser, mount (>= 2.19.1), sed (>= 4)
Conflicts: fuse:i386
Description: Filesystem in Userspace
 Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE) is a simple interface for userspace programs to export a virtual filesystem to the Linux kernel. It also aims to
 provide a secure method for non privileged users to create and mount their own filesystem implementations.
Homepage: http://fuse.sourceforge.net/
```

Comment: Strange. `sshfs` has a depency on `fuse`. What does `aptitude show fuse` say?

Comment: Are you able to `sudo sftp ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`? If not, what is its output? You may try running with an additional `-v` for extra verbosity.

Comment: Root probably can't log in to the remote system because it doesn't have the private key. Why aren't you running sshfs as your own user? What is the output of `ls -l /dev/fuse` ?